# How to Trigger LauncherDialog.Download Event by using code in geckofx browser control in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, geckofx

I need to trigger LauncherDialog Event Delegate Programmatically, but unable to do so. because, it takes much time to trigger automatically. in the mean time other functionalities depended on that code are being executed before.

Comment: What have you tried so far and what specific errors/issues are you getting?

Comment: I have used nsIURI, nsAStringBase, nsIWebBrowserPersist, nsITransfer to create a file, transfer content to the created file and opening it with a filewatcher